# Coroutine context custom getter

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm investigating kotlin coroutines related to Android after 1.0.0 release.

I found tons of examples of making scoped ViewModel (from arch components) with creating parent job and clearing it in `onCleared` or scoped Activity with job creation in `onCreate` and clearing in `onDestroy` (same with `onResume` and `onPause`). In some examples I meet this code structure (taken from [official docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/)):

```
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job
```

Is this custom getter called all times, when we start a new coroutine from this scope? Isn't it bad? Maybe it would be better to keep single scope value instead of creating a new one every time?

**[UPDATE]**

I accept that solution, if we get rid of `lateinit` job and create it isntantly, but what if I want to do something like this (what should I do? Is this solution looks like correct or not?):

```
class LifecycleCrScope: CoroutineScope, LifecycleObserver {

  private var _job: Job? = null
  override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job() + Dispatchers.Main


  fun job() : Job {
    return _job ?: createJob().also { _job = it }
  }

  fun createJob(): Job = Job() // or another implementation

  @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_PAUSE)
  fun pause() {
    _job?.cancel()
    _job = null
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could just drop the lateinit foo and do `val job = Job()` and then do `val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job` since activities should not be created or destroyed more than once (Or use `by lazy` with `coroutineContext`). But how many times per second are you `launch`ing coroutines? It's just not that important to optimize such a minor operation when you casually do collection operations all the time in ui thread methods.

Comment: You could also dispense with `val job` altogether, you need the job just once in `onDestroy` and you can get it as `coroutineContext[Job]`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I updated question

Comment: @zapl I updated question

Comment: Your implementation would be quite simpler if you used `override val coroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Main + Job() }` and `coroutineContext[Job]!!.cancel()` to cancel it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah, I get it, but what if I want to re-init coroutineContext with a new job, as in the update?

Comment: I don't think you have to cancel all your coroutines if the activity is just pausing, but as a general idea, you can re-initialize the `coroutineContext` and not just the job: `private var _coroCtx: CoroutineContext? = null; override val coroutineContext get() = _coroCtx ?: (Dispatchers.Main + Job()).also { _coroCtx = it }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hm, yes, that looks much better actually. Please, post it as answer to extend this discussion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could run into issues with thread-safety when you supply a `Job` lazily like in your update because that code is evaluated from whatever thread happens to start a coroutine.
The initial example on the other hand makes sure that the Job is setup from the Main thread and that it happens before other threads can be started in a typical android activity.

You could achieve something similar to the initial example by creating the entire `CoroutineContext` at the start of the scope. That also removes the need to compute the final context for each started coroutine. For example:

```
class LifecycleCrScope : CoroutineScope, LifecycleObserver {

    private var _ctx: CoroutineContext? = null
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = _ctx!! // throws when not within scope

    private fun startScope() {
        _ctx = Dispatchers.Main + Job()
    }

    private fun endScope() {
        _ctx!![Job]!!.cancel()  // throws only when misused, e.g. no startScope()
        _ctx = null
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_RESUME) //  <-.
    fun resume() {               //    | Beware:
        startScope()             //    | symmetric but no scope
    }                            //    | during onCreate,
                                 //    | onStart, onStop, ...
    @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_PAUSE)  //  <-.
    fun pause() {
        endScope()
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you don't like it to throw

```
class LifecycleCrScope : CoroutineScope, LifecycleObserver {
    // initially cancelled. Jobs started outside scope will not execute silently
    private var _ctx: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + Job().apply { cancel() }
    ..
    private fun endScope() {
        _ctx[Job]!!.cancel()  // should never throw
    }
    ..
```

Comment: We can throw in a different way, something kinda `get() = _ctx ?: throw IllegalStateException("called before resume")`, but looks much better, for sure